# Extract e-mail from long text(PHP)

Tags: php, string, extract

I have to find way to extract e-mail adress from webpage source code.

```
    $str=  "<a h=ref=3D.mailto:rys@adres.pl.><img src=3D.http://www.lowiecki.pl/img/list.gif=
        . border=3D.0.></a></td><td class=3D.bb.>
        $a = preg_split( "/ [:] /", $str )";
    for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++)
        echo $a[$i];
```

I tried that, but i don't know how to set limit on substring "pl".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E-mail addresses can be far more complex than the forms we are used to, see [examples of uncommon valid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses).

An almost perfect, but very complex, regular expression for matching most e-mail address forms is proposed at https://emailregex.com/.

You could use this shorter, but more restrictive, expression derived from one proposed by Jan Goyvaerts at https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html: `/\b[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9._%+-]{0,63}@(?:[A-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.){1,125}[A-Z]{2,63}\b/i`

In a PHP script, it could be implemented this way:

```
<?php
$str = "<a h=ref=3D.mailto:rys@adres.pl.><img src=3D.http://www.lowiecki.pl/img/list.gif=
        . border=3D.0.></a></td><td class=3D.bb.><a h=ref=3D.mailto:second-address@example.com.>foo</a>";

preg_match_all(
    '/\b[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9._%+-]{0,63}@(?:[A-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.){1,125}[A-Z]{2,63}\b/i', # After https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html
    quoted_printable_decode($str), # An e-mail address may be corrupted by the quoted-printable encoding.
    $matches
);

echo isset($matches[0]) ? '<pre>'.print_r($matches[0], true).'</pre>' : 'No address found.';
?>
```

This script outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => rys@adres.pl
    [1] => second-address@example.com
)
```

Make sure to call `$matches[0]` to get the found addresses.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Next code will search for an email and save it into a variable, after that you can use the result as you wish.

```
$email = preg_match_all(
  "/[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+\\.[a-z]{2,}/i",
  $str,
  $listofemails
);

if($email) {
   echo "you got a match";
}
```

Comment: My fault. I didin't explain my problem understandable. I need to find e-mails in text and save them in array.

Comment: That's what the above code does. $email is the result of checking $str (your text) and storing the findings in the $listofemails array.

Comment: Ooh yeah. I had problem with display array $listofemails so i thought maybe that is something else.